# getting unknown error in my hibernate mapping file

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have three persistent classes named:shops.class,user.class,vehicle.class and three hibernate mapping file shops.hbm.xml,users.hbm.xml,vehicle.hbm.xml

### But i am getting following error in my users and vehicle mappingg file:

```
The content of element type "class" must match
"(meta*,subselect?,cache?,synchronize*,comment?,tuplizer*,(id|composite-id),discriminator?,natural-id?,(version|timestamp)?,(property|many-to-one|one-to-one|component|dynamic-component|properties|any|map|set|list|bag|idbag|array|primitive-array)*,((join*,subclass*)|joined-subclass*|union-subclass*),loader?,sql-insert?,sql-update?,sql-delete?,filter*,fetch-profile*,resultset*,(query|sql-query)*)".
```

### shops.hbm.xml:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
> <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
> "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
> <!-- Generated Jun 7, 2017 2:04:29 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
> <hibernate-mapping>
>     <class name="persistent_classes.shops" table="SHOPS">
>         <id name="id" type="int">
>             <column name="ID" />
>             <generator class="increment" />
>         </id>
>         <version name="version_id" type="int" unsaved-value="undefined">
>             <column name="VERSION_ID" />
>         </version>
>         <property name="name" type="java.lang.String">
>             <column name="NAME" />
>         </property>
>         <property name="address" type="java.lang.String">
>             <column name="ADDRESS" />
>         </property>
>         <property name="city" type="java.lang.String">
>             <column name="CITY" />
>         </property>
>         <property name="dealername" type="java.lang.String">
>             <column name="DEALERNAME" />
>         </property>
>         <property name="dealerno" type="java.lang.String">
>             <column name="DEALERNO" />
>         </property>
>         <property name="dealeremail" type="java.lang.String">
>             <column name="DEALEREMAIL" />
>         </property>
>         <property name="password" type="java.lang.String">
>             <column name="PASSWORD" />
>         </property>
>         <property name="shops_string" type="java.lang.String">
>             <column name="SHOPS_STRING" />
>         </property>
>         <property name="login" type="boolean">
>             <column name="LOGIN" />
>         </property>
>         <list name="vehicles" inverse="false" table="VEHICLE" lazy="true">
>             <key>
>                 <column name="store_id" />
>             </key>
>             <list-index></list-index>
>             <one-to-many class="persistent_classes.vehicle" />
>         </list>
>         <map name="users" table="SHOPS_MAP" lazy="true">
>             <key>
>                 <column name="ID" />
>             </key>
>             <map-key type="java.lang.Integer"></map-key>
>             <element type="java.lang.Integer">
>                 <column name="USERS" />
>             </element>
>         </map>
>     </class>
> </hibernate-mapping>
> ```

### vehicle.hbm.xml:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
> <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
> "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
> <!-- Generated Jun 7, 2017 2:04:29 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
> <hibernate-mapping>
>     <class name="persistent_classes.vehicle" table="VEHICLE">
>         <id name="id" type="int">
>             <column name="ID" />
>             <generator class="increment" />
>         </id>
>         <property name="stock" type="int">
>             <column name="STOCK" />
>         </property>
>         <version name="version_id" type="int" unsaved-value="undefined">
>             <column name="VERSION_ID" />
>         </version>
>         <property name="name" type="java.lang.String">
>             <column name="NAME" />
>         </property>
>         <property name="company" type="java.lang.String">
>             <column name="COMPANY" />
>         </property>
>         <property name="milage" type="java.lang.String">
>             <column name="MILAGE" />
>         </property>
>         <property name="year" type="java.lang.String">
>             <column name="YEAR" />
>         </property>
>         <property name="priceoriginal" type="java.lang.String">
>             <column name="PRICEORIGINAL" />
>         </property>
>         <property name="priceoffer" type="java.lang.String">
>             <column name="PRICEOFFER" />
>         </property>
>         <property name="vehicle_string" type="java.lang.String">
>             <column name="VEHICLE_STRING" />
>         </property>
>     </class>
> </hibernate-mapping>
> ```

### users.hbm.xml:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
> <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
> "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
> <!-- Generated Jun 7, 2017 2:04:40 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
> <hibernate-mapping>
>     <class name="persistent_classes.users" table="USERS">
>         <id name="id" type="int">
>             <column name="ID" />
>             <generator class="increment" />
>         </id>
>         <map name="points" table="user_points" cascade="all">
>             <key  column="user_id" />
>             <index column="shop_id" type="integer"></index>
>             <element column="points" type="string"></element>
>             </map>
>         <version name="version_id" type="int" unsaved-value="undefined">
>             <column name="VERSION_ID" />
>         </version>
>         <property name="login" type="boolean">
>             <column name="LOGIN" />
>         </property>
>         <property name="name" type="java.lang.String">
>             <column name="NAME" />
>         </property>
>         <property name="password" type="java.lang.String">
>             <column name="PASSWORD" />
>         </property>
>         <property name="email" type="java.lang.String">
>             <column name="EMAIL" />
>         </property>
>         <property name="mobno" type="java.lang.String">
>             <column name="MOBNO" />
>         </property>
>         <property name="address" type="java.lang.String">
>             <column name="ADDRESS" />
>         </property>
>         <property name="users_string" type="java.lang.String">
>             <column name="USERS_STRING" />
>         </property>
>     </class>
> </hibernate-mapping>
> ```

I know this question is asked many times but all of that were related to not using  tag. But i had used this tag in all files but still getting this error in users and vehicle file.
Please Help i am badly stuck with this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`version` must be defined before `property` and `map`

Move it to be right after `id` definition in the `users` and `vehicle` `hbm`